# Proper inter-column spacing and vertical alignment in a tabular environment

Tags: tables

I have code for a tabular environment that is not displayed properly.  I have the right parenthesis following the lower-case Roman numerals `i`, `iii`, and `v` aligned, and I would like to have the right parenthesis following the lower-case Roman numerals `ii`, `iv`, and `vi` aligned.  I thought that I had made the inter-column spacing  1.5 inches ... but that didn't happen.  Why didn't the command `\hspace*{2em}` preceding the tabular environment indent the left edge of the box containing the contents of the tabular environment by `2em`?  (I know there are other packages to use to display this table.  I want to use the tabular environment and have my code modified.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\noindent The following sets have either a least upper bound or a greatest lower bound of 1. \\
\noindent \hspace*{2em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5in}
\begin{tabular}{r@{}lr@{}l}
\textbf{i.) }   &   $\displaystyle{\left\{1 - \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$
\textbf{ii.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\left\{1 + \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{iii.) } &   $\displaystyle{\left\{9\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{10^{n}} \mid N \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$
\textbf{iv.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\left\{1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{v.) }   &   $\displaystyle{\left\{\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{2} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$
\textbf{vi.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\left\{\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing a `&` after the first math column, that's why the second roman number column is not aligned

Comment: You mention `\hspace*{2em}` but I don't see this instruction in your code.

Comment: @Mico   Thanks.  I see that I have it highlighted on `WinEdt`; I must have gotten distracted before I hit `Ctrl P` and pasted it onto the code in my post.  I just included it in the code.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire - Indeed, providing the previously-missing `\hspace{2em` instruciton makes a big difference. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer  Thanks.  I posted a response that included your suggested edit.  Why is the tabular environment shifted rightward so much?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire - Unless you override the default settings (e.g., by inserting `@{}`), LaTeX inserts whitespace in the amount of `\tabcolsep` to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column.

Comment: @Mico  I just posted this question at "Proper indentation from left margin of a tabular environment."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle}l<$}
\newcommand\mmid{\;\middle\vert\;}
\begin{document}

\noindent 
The following sets have either a least upper bound or a greatest lower bound of 1. 

\noindent\hspace{2em}% <-- added "\hspace{2em}" 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3ex}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{2}{r@{\hspace{1em}}L} @{}}
\textbf{i.)}   & 
\left\{1 - \frac{1}{n} \mmid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} &
\textbf{ii.)}  & 
\left\{1 + \frac{1}{n} \mmid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \\
\textbf{iii.)} &  
\biggl\{9\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{10^{n}} \biggm|N \in \mathbb{N\biggr\} &   
\left\{1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} \mmid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \\
\textbf{v.)}   &  
\left\{\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{2} \mmid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} &
\textbf{vi.)}  &  
\left\{\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{n} \mmid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This display is very close to what I want.  The lower-case roman numeral `iii` seems to be at the left margin.  I think that putting the `\noindent \hspace*{2em}` before the tabular environment will shift it rightward appropriately.  (I forgot to put that in my original post.)

Comment: What do the `@{} *{2}` and the `@{}` instruct `TeX` to draw for the tabular environment?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire - I've updated the answer and screenshot to incorporate the piece of information about `\hspace*{2em}. In a `tabular` setup `*{2}{...}` means that the material in the second curly brace is performed twice. `@{}` suppresses any whitespace in that location.

Comment: @Mico, great answer.  In my attempt, to solve that problem on my own, I added `\newcolumntype{R}{>{\bfseries}r<{.)}}` to the preamble.  Hence I only wrote `i & \left ...` into my table body.  Saves also some typing trouble.

Comment: @Mico  I posted a response to ask you the following question.  Why is the display of the tabular environment in my code shifted a lot more rightward from my code more than the tabular environment from your code?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is easier to use a dedicated tool for what you want to obtain, namely the `tasks` package.  Each `\task` is referable. I added a `\set` command for the `set-builder` notation, inspired by code in the `mathtools` documentation:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{showframe} \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}%
\usepackage{xparse} %

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

\begin{document}

\noindent The following sets have either a least upper bound or a greatest lower bound of 1.

\settasks{label-width=2em, label-align=right, item-indent=4em, counter-format =\bfseries tsk[r].), column-sep=1in, before-skip=1.5ex, after-skip=1.5ex }
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task $ \set*{1 - \frac{1}{n} ; n ∈ \mathbb{N}} $; \task $ \set*{1 + \frac{1}{n}; d n ∈ \mathbb{N}} $;
  \task $ \set*{9∑_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{10ⁿ} ; N ∈ \mathbb{N}} $;
  \task $ \set*{1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)ⁿ ; n ∈ \mathbb{N}} $;
  \task $ \set*{√[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{2} ; n ∈ \mathbb{N}} $;
  \task $ \set*{√[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{n} ; n ∈ \mathbb{N}} $.
\end{tasks}
Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text

\end{document}
```

[image]