# Proper indentation from left margin of a tabular environment

Tags: tables, indentation

How do I get the tabular environment obtained from the following code indented from the left margin by `\hspace{2em}`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\noindent The following sets have either a least upper bound or a greatest lower bound of 1. \\
\noindent \hspace*{2em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5in}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3ex}
\begin{tabular}{r@{}lr@{}l}
\textbf{i.) }   &   $\displaystyle{\left\{1 - \frac{1}{n} \;\middle\vert\; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$
&
\textbf{ii.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\left\{1 + \frac{1}{n} \;\middle\vert\; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{iii.) } &   $\displaystyle{\left\{9\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{10^{n}} \;\middle\vert\; N \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$
&
\textbf{iv.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\left\{1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} \;\middle\vert\; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{v.) }   &   $\displaystyle{\left\{\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{2} \;\middle\vert\; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$
&
\textbf{vi.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\left\{\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} n]{n} \;\middle\vert\; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}}$
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}lr@{}l}`, using the leading `@{}` to cancel the `\tabcolsep` that normally goes there.

Comment: @Mico  You suggested using `\middle\vert` in the post "Proper inter-column spacing and vertical alignment in a tabular environment."  I recall that this was a common typesetting practice in set-builder notation from older textbooks.  Now, I see textbooks predominantly using `\mid`.  I think that I prefer the older format.

Comment: `\displaystyle` doesn't take an argument so `\displaystyle{...}` is the same as `\displaystyle ...`

Comment: @David Carlisle  Thanks.  I did not know that.  I will probably still use braces in order to separate the "e" in `\displaystyle` from an algebraic expression.  I guess programmers just use a space character.

Comment: I recommend you using a better interface such as `tasks` that has already been suggested to you at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346974/

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire it is a bad idea to use the braces, in the table `l` column they just do nothing but if the inline math is in a paragraph then the extra group will force all space to be frozen and not stretch or shrink and will prevent line breaking/

Answer (score 3):

```
\noindent \hspace*{2em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5in}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3ex}
\begin{tabular}{r@{}lr@{}l}
```

starts a paragraph with no indentation then adds three space tokens which produce three times a normal inter-word space, then the tabular starts, with the left edge of the tabular including .5in space.

You probably want

```
\noindent \hspace*{2em}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5in}%
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3ex}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}lr@{}l}
```

which avoids the spaces or

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5in}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3ex}
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace*{2em}}r@{}lr@{}l}
```

which adds the space tokens in vertical mode where they are ignored